# Google Drive's document doesn't display the image in my html upload anymore

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Google Drive is not showing images on HTML Documents uploaded by both the Google Drive webpage and by the APIs.

I was using Google Docs APIs to upload HTML files referencing public images (using  tag) from the Internet. Once the file is uploaded from my Android App, Drive API automatically converted the HTML file to a Google Document and displays the referenced images fine.

Recently, I found Google Drive just print "*" in the place of the embedded image, and I cannot see the image reference anymore.

Here's the HTML I uploaded for test

```
<!doctype html> 
<HTML> 
<HEAD> 
<title>Test</title>  
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'  />  
</head>  
<body>
Document conversion html > document and Image display test
<img src='https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-28-5438975338610688-hp.gif' />
</body>
```

and the way to re-produce problem.

```
1. make simple html file with above file content.
2. upload it to Google drive
3. right-click on the uploaded html file > Open with > Google Docs
4. then, you will see only the * is displayed where image supposed to be.
```

I feel that there's something wrong in document conversion. Any idea how to walk around?

Comment: FYI, Embedded image(data uri) does not work neither.

Comment: We had similar problem with ODT file upload.

Comment: For my case, it seems it works again now (2 hours ago, it didn't work well. This last one hour, it seems it works fine again).

Comment: Thanks guys, I also see the problem is resolved. I guess Google Drive did some fix.

Comment: Today, embedded images are replace with "...", what the hell is going on?